# Mobile site - on native android browser doesn't resize right (and can't always get keyboard focus), does on Chrome

Tags: android, jquery, css, mobile, backbone.js

The layout for our new mobile site, when viewed on Android phones, works fine in Chrome but not in the native Android browser or Dolphin.

(Note: I am not the coder, I'm a troubleshooter, so I don't know why certain choices were made)

**Problem 1: The layout isn't at the proper zoom.**   The page displays wider than the window.  I can get it to zoom out to the proper zoom, but it's not being automatic like it should be.

**Problem 2: Clicking usually doesn't lead to focus**  I'm supposed to be able to click on an icon on the landing page to be taken to a login page.  Sometimes I can, but that usually happens after I've been frustratedly tapping at the same point for a while.  And then, even if I manage to get to the login page, tapping on the input fields doesn't bring up the keyboard.  (it does highlight the box in blue, indicating that some part of the action has been recognized).  In other words, I can't log in (and thus can't look for other symptoms elsewhere in the site).

Needless to say, this is a rather large blocker, both for usability and testing.

I've been doing a **lot** of research, and trying a variety of things (like setting initial-scale and/or maximum-scale to 1), but no luck yet.  I'm about two steps away from introducing my android phone to my sledgehammer, so it seemed time to ask for help.

**Details**
- The site is built in Backbone with jQuery.
- Mobile detection is done using Șerban Ghiță's Mobile Detect (mobiledetect.net)

Part of the Mobile detection code:

```
<?php if ($is_ios) { if ($deviceType=="tablet" ) { ?>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024,user-scalable=no" />
<?php } else { ?>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=640,user-scalable=no" />
<?php } } else { if ($deviceType=="tablet" ) { ?>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.666667; 
     maximum-scale=0.666667; user-scalable=0">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<?php } else { ?>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=640,user-scalable=no" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<?php } } ?>
```

I'm not sure which bits of the CSS would be useful, I haven't seen anything helpful when I've gone through the code, but clearly I'm not sure what I'm looking for  (and boy do I miss Firebug and the various "click on an element and see what its css is" tools for web)

About the only even vaguely relevant difference between Chrome and Dolphin/Native Android Browser that I've found (but this probably isn't the actual relevant one) is that, using the www.portvie.ws tool (from http://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/adaptive-design-fixed-widths-and-tablets), Chrome thinks the device width is 320 x 534, while the other two browsers think it's 480x800.

Am I at least looking in the right direction for the source of this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be related to the scale/zoom.  We found two solutions to the problem:

1) When setting the viewport, width=device-width; and, for Android phones, set the minimum and maximum scale to 0.5.   This solved the layout problem, but not the focus problem (but did narrow the focus problem down so that, of the phones tested, it was only a problem on a phone running Android 4.0.4)

2) For Android phones, set the zoom to 0.5.  This fixed the focus problem, but made the font size unreasonably small, so we went with the first solution.

Hope our adventures can help someone else...